# Upgrade builds Version gets updated but not the files (cache deletion)

Tags: android, beta

The android build with version (say 4.0.1) and with build number 40100 is installed successfully and when try to upgrade for next version say 4.0.2 and with build number 40200 is getting upgraded.The thing is that file downloaded in the local path is not updated which means while updating have to delete the cache .How to perform that programatically? Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you know that its not upgrading what's happening you are installing the new build ?

Comment: @Swayangjit A Html file  (downloaded in local device)has to get updated and presenting that in the webview and that file not getting updated in local path itself .

Comment: are you building with gradle ?

Comment: with fastlane comment